# Same CSS in Mobile & Desktop with different margins/paddings

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I have a site where the paddings and margins are shown differently between devices. I have screenshots of the same site in an Android device and in my desktop PC:

Site in the mobile device:

[image: Mobile]

Desktop resized:

[image: Desktop, resized]

Here is the CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* Diario */
* {
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 130%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#page {
}
#page header {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
#page footer {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

#page article {
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2em 0.5em #000;
}
#page article p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#page article p.meta {
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #999;
}

#big {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#big article {
}


#normal {
}
#normal article {
}

#normal article:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>El diario - <?php echo date('d-m-Y') ?></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page">

            <header>
                <p>El diario - <?php echo date('d-m-Y') ?></p>
            </header>

            <section id="big">
                <article class="main">
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>

                <article class="sub">
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>

                <article class="sub">
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>

                <article class="sub">
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>
            </section>

            <section id="normal">
                <article>
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>

                <article>
                    <h1>Titulo de la noticia que ud. esta leyendo ahora mismo</h1>
                    <p class="meta">Publicado hace 2 días</p>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </article>
            </section>

            <footer>
                (C)<?php echo date('Y') ?> Leprosystems
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I've searching for a similar issue, the only answer I've been found so far is to add the `-text-size-adjust: none;` piece of code, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: why not use media queries? Take a look here for some default definitions of devices. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Yes, I will use media queries, but this must be resolved first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair for days, the answer(simple, as usual with this kind of problems):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

So, after kicking myself, I stablished a rule: ALWAYS use `viewport` metatag when developing with device compatibility in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I understood the question wrong but I think that his question was *why* his website has different margins in different browsers.

**In this case you must know that :**

> every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain amount of padding to almost everything. 
>   - http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

To solve it, you can use a "css reset" like normalize (https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) which will make your website look the same no matter the web browser.

Comment: Im doing a reset at the top of the css stylessheet

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and(min-width:320px){
//what ever styles.
}

@media screen and(min-width:990px){
//what ever styles.
}
```

media queries would do best for this consent

Answer (score -1):

How is it different? 
You can always use the universal css selector `*` to do a "reset"

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
```